# Check whether a string is a number

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to check whether a string is a number. I have tried the following, which works separately but not together.

```
if (i.matches("\\d{2} | [0-9]"))
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: use `^\d+$` , which language are you using(I guess it's Java)?

Comment: Do you have a limit on the length of string?

Comment: Yes it is java. yes 2 digits

Comment: @light , atmost two digts or just two digits

Comment: You must not put spaces in your regex unless you want to match a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to check whether the given string  is a one or two digit number or not.

```
if (i.matches("\\d{1,2}"))
```

Note that `matches` method won't need anchors. It would do an exact string match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Exception mechanism to provided by Java to address this problem.

The constructor [`BigInteger(String val)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String)) of class `BigInteger` throws [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) if the provided string is not a valid decimal number.

```
public static boolean isNumber(String string) {
    if (string != null) {
        try {
            new BigInteger(string);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can also use another constructor of class `BigInteger` - `BigInteger(String val, int radix)` to check whether the provided string is a number with base `radix`.

Eg: 76576ACFED65 is a valid number with base 16.